# Tiling back patio over concrete, with slant towards drain

Tags: concrete, tile, drain

We have a small 9' x 9' concrete back patio that has a drain in the center (see pic).  The cement is angled towards the drain, so when it rains there actually isn't too much water build up, which is great.

[image]

We're thinking about adding tile to the patio to make it a little more personable and 'nicer', but are not really sure how to deal with the drain and the angled concrete.  Are there resources out there showing how to diy tile over angled concrete with a drain?  Do we need to level things out first, but if so, how do we prevent water build up?  Should I put down a water impermeable layer first?

Thanks!

Comment: Consider staining rather than tiling. Better project for a less experienced person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to level things out. Tile is set in a mortar bed (a fairly thin layer by historical standards, but a bed nonetheless), and that will allow you to handle the transitions from one plane to another with no problem. You may choose to leave seams over the existing control joints, though. Whether you do may depend on whether there are actual cracks at those locations.

For the drain, you'll just cut the tile to fit, or you could get clever and slice the tile to create a drain and go over the existing. That could be prone to cracking, though.

Tile is a great project for a new DIYer. Don't be intimidated by the fact that you have to cut tiles. It's neither difficult nor dangerous with the right tools and knowhow. This is my opinion, though, and that part of your question is technically off topic.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely beautiful stains nowadays for outdoor concrete slabs easy to do less than $80 you can get you a basement / driveway/garage flooring covering comes in a can you just pour it on usually is a really nice glaze and absolutely beautiful depends on what designs you want the stains are relatively easy and pretty cheap

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Please take the [tour] to see how we're different from a discussion forum.